# What Function to Use For Trace Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

While there is a function used for Trace Matrix as seen below:

```
sum(diag(matrix))
```

This may incorrectly give you a result if the matrix is not Square (i.e. an "n x n" size). Are there any other inbuilt functions for running "Trace" of a matrix?

Comment: As you noted, the `matrixcalc` package has a `matrix.trace` function. You can see the function code by typing `matrix.trace` in the console.

Comment: The built-in `stats` package has an internal function for this: `stats:::Tr`. And it does exactly `sum(diag(matrix))`. However, it's not recommended to use internal functions.

Answer (score 2):

Package: psych

Function: tr()

Example:

```
> x <- matrix(replicate(9,1), ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
> tr(x)
[1] 3

> x <- matrix(replicate(12,1), ncol = 4, nrow = 3)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1
> tr(x)
Fehler in tr(x) : m must be a square matrix
```

("Fehler" means error)

Moreover

Package: matrixcalc

Function: matrix.trace

Comment: All that `tr(x)` does is: 1) check if matrix is square, 2) `sum(diag(x), na.rm = TRUE)`. So you might as well just keep your code and run the check yourself without additional packages.

Comment: I thought my answer to be pertaining to the question, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a quick function to test if the object is a matrix and then test if it is also square.

```
    tr <- function (m)
{
  total_sum <- 0
  if(is.matrix(m))
    {
      row_count <- nrow(m)
      col_count <- ncol(m)
      if(row_count == col_count)
      {
        total_sum <-sum(diag(m))
        total_sum
      }
      else
      {
        message ('Matrix is not square')
      }
  }
  else
  {
    message( 'Object is not a matrix')

  }
}
```

I also found the following package for Matrix.Trace:

[Matrixcalc](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/matrixcalc/docs/matrix.trace)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using eigenvalues

`# first find eigenvalues 
 e = eigen(matrix)
 # Calculate the trace of the matrix, and compare with the sum of the   eigenvalues.
 # function to calculate the trace using sum of the diagonal
 trace <- function(data)sum(diag(data))
 trace(H) 
 # using sum of the eigenvalues
 sum(e$values)`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Don't try this on a large matrix.

Comment: It does not. This breaks if the matrix is standardized, in which case, what you get is the matrix rank.  Solution not advisable.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use native `diag` function :

```r
# Create a random id matrix with value from 0 to 100
x <- matrix(c(sample(1:100, 9, replace = TRUE)), 3, 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   37   52   14
# [2,]   20   79   70
# [3,]   52   97   66

diag(x)
# [1] 37 79 66
```